# Pop elements conditional on their content

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The borrow-checker is giving me a hard time to find an elegant implementation. Here is a minimal example:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut vec1 = VecDeque::new();
    vec1.push_back(2.);

    let mut vec2 = VecDeque::new();
    vec2.push_back(1.);

    while let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (vec1.front_mut(), vec2.front_mut()) {
        if x < y {
            *y -= *x;
            vec1.pop_front();
        } else {
            *x -= *y;
            vec2.pop_front();
        }
    }

    assert_eq!(vec2.len(), 0);
    assert_eq!(vec1.pop_front(), Some(1.));
}
```

This will not compile:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `vec1` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:13:13
   |
10 |     while let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (vec1.front_mut(), vec2.front_mut()) {
   |                                     ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
13 |             vec1.pop_front();
   |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
18 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `vec2` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
10 |     while let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (vec1.front_mut(), vec2.front_mut()) {
   |                                                       ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
16 |             vec2.pop_front();
   |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
17 |         }
18 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

The `if x < y` scope is necessarily nested in `x` and `y`'s scope, so how then can I mutate `vec1`/`vec2` conditional on their first element?

Comment: Question to people familiar with the plans for non-lexical lifetimes:  Will this code simply work once NLLs are implemented?  To me it looks like it could.

Comment: @SvenMarnach From what I understand of NLLs, yes, this code should simply work.

Comment: NLLs have landed in Nightly, and this indeed works out fo the box: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=04eaefe9e322e3b959ff7fca62e829f7&version=nightly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut vec1 = VecDeque::new();
    vec1.push_back(2.);

    let mut vec2 = VecDeque::new();
    vec2.push_back(1.);

    loop {
        let pop_vec1;

        if let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (vec1.front_mut(), vec2.front_mut()) {
            if x < y {
                *y -= *x;
                pop_vec1 = true;
            } else {
                *x -= *y;
                pop_vec1 = false;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }

        if pop_vec1 {
            vec1.pop_front();
        } else {
            vec2.pop_front();
        }
    }

    assert_eq!(vec2.len(), 0);
    assert_eq!(vec1.pop_front(), Some(1.));
}
```

or if you prefer a loop with less lines:

```
loop {
    let pop_vec1 = match (vec1.front_mut(), vec2.front_mut()) {
        (Some(ref x), Some(ref mut y)) if x < y => { **y -= **x; true },
        (Some(x), Some(y)) => { *x -= *y; false },
        _ => break,
    };

    VecDeque::pop_front(if pop_vec1 { &mut vec1 } else { &mut vec2 });
}
```

Not very elegant, but it works.

`VecDeque` is missing a method [like `Vec::drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter). Maybe the Rust team will add it.

Comment: If you wish a `drain_filter` to be added to `VecDeque`, the simplest way to get it is to create a RFC to propose it, then implement it. I surmise it should not be too complicated using `Vec` as an example.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I know nothing about the processes in Rust. This is not the "simplest" for me. I am far more afraid by the "administrative" side of the thing than technical.

Comment: Maybe simplest wasn't the right word... "quickest" might be better. Another option would be to mention it on IRC and hope someone picks it up. It's a small enough task that someone wanted to get their toes wet in the Rust standard library could reasonably handle it.

Comment: For what its worth, [`drain_filter` was added to `LinkedList` without an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46262) (only 2 weeks ago!), so I'd imagine you wouldn't necessarily need one for this either.

Comment: @JoeClay Actually, the RFC has already been already done, it seems: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2140

Comment: I was hoping not having to use a flag variable, but all in all this is a reasonably clean solution, and hey, it works ;)

Comment: @Boiethios: The issues section of the RFCs repo mainly contains suggestions for RFCs, rather than the RFCs themselves (which are filed as pull requests) - as far as I can tell, nobody took that issue forward as a full RFC.